# VB.NET - Better code to get if two processes are running

Tags: vb.net

I need to know if at least one of two processes are running, let's call them "process1" and "process2". Don't need to know which one is running.
I'd like to know what's the faster code and with less resource impact.

Actually I'm using:

```
Dim RunningProcesses() As Process
Dim IsRunning As Boolean = False

RunningProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("process1")
If RunningProcesses.Count > 1 Then
    IsRunning = True
End If

RunningProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("process2")
If RunningProcesses.Count > 1 Then
    IsRunning = True
End If
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're using the same code for both processes so I don't understand your question about which is faster as they do the same thing, also shouldn't you be checking if RunningProcesses.Count > 0 else you could have one instance of the process running and it return False.

Comment: This best over at [**code review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function which you can pass process names to, you could do something like

```
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Module1

    Function IsAnyProcessRunning(procNames As List(Of String)) As Boolean
        Return Process.GetProcesses.Any(Function(proc) procNames.Any(Function(n) String.Compare(n, proc.ProcessName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0))
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim procs As New List(Of String) From {"devenv", "Firefox"}
        Console.WriteLine(IsAnyProcessRunning(procs))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I made it so that the process name is not case-sensitive as I found that "Firefox" is actually "firefox" in the process name.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim IsRunning As Boolean = False


If Process.GetProcessesByName("process1").Count > 0 Then
   IsRunning = True
else    
    If Process.GetProcessesByName("process2").Count > 0 Then
        IsRunning = True
    End If
End If
```

This way you don't run the second check if the first delivers true already. And IMO it has to be Count > 0...oh, and did not test it, just out of my head

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the Count > 1 was a transcription error. Your solution is working fine!